# why my conditions do not display anything?

Tags: python-3.x

my code choose a random number and the user must find the random number 
but if I write a bigger or smaller number it doesn't display anything

```
from random import *

nb_au_hasard = (randint(1, 50))
print(nb_au_hasard)
nb_choisi = (int(input("choisi un nombre entre 1 et 50")))
while nb_choisi == nb_au_hasard:
    if nb_choisi < nb_au_hasard:
     print("le nombre est plus grand")

    else:
     print("le nombre est plus petit")

     if nb_choisi == nb_au_hasard:
         print("tu as reussi ")
         break
```

Comment: I believe you mean `while nb_choisi != nb_au_hasard`. The loop will never be entered with how you have it now, unless they guess correctly from the start.

Comment: it works thank you